# Error Creating Trigger Unknown System Variable

Tags: mysql, triggers, mysql-error-1193

I am trying to create a trigger in mysql using the following:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ins_daft BEFORE INSERT ON jos_ezrealty
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
SET preschool = livingarea*10.76391041671
END;
```

When I do I get the following error:

```
Error
SQL query:

CREATE TRIGGER ins_daft BEFORE INSERT ON jos_ezrealty
FOR EACH
ROW BEGIN 
SET preschool = livingarea * 10.76391041671 END

MySQL said: Documentation

#1193 - Unknown system variable 'preschool'
```

I am trying to have the value of one field converted to square feet by multiplying by 10.76391041671. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any time you want to reference the columns of a row that fired the trigger, qualify them like `NEW.column_name`.

Otherwise the `SET` command thinks you want to set a MySQL configuration variable called `preschool`.

Comment: I made the change and now I get this:SQL query:

CREATE TRIGGER ins_daft BEFORE INSERT ON jos_ezrealty
FOR EACH
ROW BEGIN 
SET NEW.preschool =  'livingarea*10.76391041671' END

MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 3

Comment: Each statement in the body of the trigger needs a semicolon (`;`) to terminate it.